# What is the best data structure to sort an array with duplicated elements?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, language-agnostic

If an array contains duplicated elements, what data structure is better for sorting?

Could B tree work?

Comment: Um, what? Every sorting algorithm correctly handles duplicates, and a lot of them even maintain the relative order of items which compare as equal (this is called a stable sort). An array is also fine, because it can contain duplicate elements. Please clarify.

Comment: B-trees are *always* sorted (as are a number of other ADTs). If it is better to keep an always-sorted structure or to sort-on-demand really depends upon other requirements/usage .. but the question seems to be asking something orthogonal to this. While the comparison sorting O(n log n) time limits apply, there the different approaches amortize the complexity differently, etc.

Comment: I just want to find out a better sorting algorithm that has smaller Big O. And everytime I insert a new element, I want to keep the order.

Comment: @FreyaRen If the sorted order must *always* be maintained, then use the applicable tree, heap, trie, etc (Wikipedia is a good starting place to read up on the fundamental differences/rules). If the data just needs to be sorted at some point, consider a simple array/list and sort-on-demand. The list *can* consume less memory at any one point, and can be sorted in O(n log n), but the sort is *not amortized* as with trees and other such structures. Also there are "eventual sort" algorithms, etc. It **depends on *the use-case*, the *real* requirements, and *real* limitations**.

Comment: So, my point is: don't invent a problem which doesn't exist; just use the structure is easiest to work with unless there are other concerns/limitations :-) SO is best when asking "practical, answerable" questions - which generally starts with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *a fixed and small range of element values* you can use counting sort algorithm, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Its complexity is `O(n + k)`, where `n` is the size of your array, and `k` is, basically, the amount of different possible elements.

The point is to calculate the number of same elements, and then insert them in the right order.

Comment: This depends if the data in the array to be sorted has a range of values.

Comment: Of course it does. It has the `O(TotalNumberOfElements)` complexity.

Comment: That's Big Oh notation for time complexity, but you will need to create an array of X elements to use as buckets. If you're going to sort a 10 element in array with data varying between 1 an 100000, this will be a bad approach.

Comment: I just thought the OP has specific data to sort, so standard O(n log n) is bad for him.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza. Yes, if the elements are not in a range of values, counting sort will not work. Is comparison sort(O(n*logn)) the only way I could use?

Comment: @FreyaRen counting sort works better for a small range, because it consumes lot of memory (at least a copy of the initial array). You can use other `O(n)` sort algorithms like [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) or [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) but these algorithms depend heavily on the data being sortered and require more memory. You should always remember when programming, there is this *memory vs performance* issue, and is up to you what you preffer.

Comment: @FreyaRen as a side note, this would depend if you sort the data while your array is being filled or if you sort it while having your array already filled. These approaches would define how *fast* your application could be.